# I'm getting KeyError while parsing a data file in python

Tags: python, parsing, keyerror

```
def loadMovieLens(path='C:\Users\karan\Desktop\ml-100k'):
  # Load data
  prefs={}
  for line in open(path+'/new1.data'):
      (user,title,rating,ts)=line.split('\t')[0:4]
      prefs[user][title]=float(rating)
  return prefs
```

I'm getting a KeyError while parsing the file.

Comment: Can you share your data file contents?

Comment: `prefs[user]` doesn't exist.  You have to make it.

Comment: Like @PatrickHaugh said. You can create `prefs[user]` like so `prefs[user] = {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary has no keys yet, so `data[user]` won't exist. You can have Python add a default value for missing keys by using the `dict.setdefault()` method:

```
prefs.setdefault(user, {})[title] = float(rating)
```

The above tells `prefs` to add `{}` (an empty dictionary) as a value for the key named in `user` if that key doesn't exist yet. Either way, the existing or new value is then returned.

With a few small improvements, the complete function then becomes:

```
def loadMovieLens(path='C:\Users\karan\Desktop\ml-100k'):
    prefs = {}
    with open(os.path.join(path, 'new1.data')) as f:
        for line in f:
            user, title, rating, ts = line.split('\t', 4)[:4]
            prefs.setdefault(user, {})[title] = float(rating)
    return prefs
```

I added a `with` statement (so the file is closed properly when reading is done), used `os.path.join()` to build the path (so it handles path separators independent of the current operating system) and limited splitting to 4 times.

You could switch to the `csv` module to handle splitting on tabs too.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in open(path+'/new1.data'):
      (user,title,rating,ts)=line.split('\t')[0:4]
      if prefs[user]:
          prefs[user][title]=float(rating)
      else:
          prefs[user] = {title: float(rating)}
```

You have to define the dictionary `prefs[user]` before you can add mappings to it

Answer (score 0):

You try, to set update dictionaries, that does not exists. So you have to generate for each user a dictionary before using it. Best, use `defaultdict` for automatic dict generation:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def loadMovieLens(path=r'C:\Users\karan\Desktop\ml-100k'):
    prefs = defaultdict(dict)
    with open(os.path.join(path, 'new1.data')) as lines:
        for line in lines:
            user, title, rating, _ts = line.split('\t', 3)
            prefs[user][title] = float(rating)
    return prefs
```